# CakePHPにマークダウン機能を付けたいですが、エラーが解決できません。

Tags: cakephp

現在メモ帳アプリでマークダウン機能を実装しようとしてgithubからマークダウンプラグインを導入して手順通りに進めていたのですがこのような
エラーがでてしまいました。
検証して調べたのですがロードコンポーネントがうまく読み込めていないみたいです。
どのように解決すれば良いでしょうか？
こちらがgithubのソースです。
https://github.com/ivanamat/cakephp3-markdown/blob/master/README.md
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コード

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash'); // FlashComponent をインクルード
    $this->Auth->allow(['tags']);
    $this->loadComponent('Markdown.Markdown');
}
public $components=[
    'Markdown'=>[
      'className' => 'Markdown.Markdown'
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: READMEに「...or load the component in the array of components」とあるように `$this->loadComponent` と `$components` はどちらか排他的ではありませんか？

Comment: $comenetsプロパティを削除したところエラーがなくなりました。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

hinaloe さんのコメントにある通り、 `$this->loadComponent` と `$components` 双方でMarkdownコンポーネントを呼び出しているため、重複エラーが発生しています。

コントローラーの $components プロパティによるコンポーネントの呼び出しは非推奨となっていますので、`loadComponent`メソッドを使用すべきです。

コントローラーの `$components` プロパティから`Markdown`の項目を削除してください。

Comment: loadComponentと$componentsが重複してエラーが発生していたのですね。$componentsプロパティを削除したところ無事エラーがなくなりました。ありがとうございました！